# test resources not found after mvn install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have a simple test class in default Maven folder structure that is using h2 database. It is initialized in this constructor:

```
    private static DataSource dataSource() {
          JdbcDataSource jdbcDataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
          jdbcDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/resources/create_table.sql'\\;runscript from 'classpath:/resources/add_test_data.sql'");
          jdbcDataSource.setUser("sa");
          jdbcDataSource.setPassword("");
          return jdbcDataSource;
        }
```

I have two files, create_table.sql and add_test_data.sql that are located under /test/resources/.
This test class runs fine in Eclipse and from CLI after I have used Eclipses Maven "force update". But now if I try mvn clean install, I get error when it tries to run the test class: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource /resources/create_table.sql".

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you see a target folder with any resources in there? The path might be `create_table.sql` rather than `resources/create_table.sql`

Comment: I can see an empty folder: \target\generated-test-sources\test-annotations.
But why does the test run before mvn install?